# Python Regex - find string between html tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to extract the string between Html tags. I can see that similar questions have been asked on stack overflow before, but I am completely new to python and I am struggling.

So if I have

```
<b>Bold Stuff</b>
```

I want to have a regular expression that leaves me with

```
Bold Stuff
```

But all of my solutions so far have left me with things like

```
>Bold Stuff<
```

I would really appreciate any help with this.

I had

```
>.*?<
```

And I have seen a question on stack overflow with suggested solution

```
>([^<>]*)<
```

But neither of these are working for me. Please could someone explain how to write a regex that says "find me the string between characters x and y not including x and y".

Thanks for any help

Comment: `>([^<>]*)<` this with `re.findall` should have worked

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> a = '<b>Bold Stuff</b>'
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'>(.+?)<', a)
['Bold Stuff']
>>> re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', a)[0] # non-greedy mode
'Bold Stuff'
>>> re.findall(r'>(.+?)<', a)[0] # or this, also is non-greedy mode
'Bold Stuff'
>>> re.findall(r'>(.*)<', a)[0] # greedy mode
'Bold Stuff'
>>>
```

At this point, both of greedy mode and non-greedy mode can work.

You're using the first non-greedy mode. Here is an example about what about non-greedy mode and  greedy mode:

```
>>> a = '<b>Bold <br> Stuff</b>'
>>> re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', a)[0]
'Bold '
>>> re.findall(r'>(.*)<', a)[0]
'Bold <br> Stuff'
>>>
```

And here is about what is [`(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> **(...)**
>
> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group;
>
> the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string with the \number special sequence, described below.
>
> To match the literals `(` or `)`, use `\(` or `\)`, or enclose them inside a character class: `[(] [)]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe simpler to just remove the HTML tags, leaving the content:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('<[^<>]+>', '', '<b>Bold Stuff</b>')
'Bold Stuff'
>>>
```

Note that using regexes to remove HTML tags is frequently considered bad practice compared to using a proper HTML parser, but it might be ok if you know your content and can rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your issue is related to the [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) returned from `re.search`. In that case the match items can be accessed by the `group()` function. However, the first group is the whole match, but you wanted to get parenthesized subgroup.

```
text = '<b>Bold Stuff</b>'

m = re.search('>([^<>]*)<', text)
print (m.group(0)) # the whole match: >Bold Stuff<
print (m.group())  # the same as with the zero argument
print (m.group(1)) # the first parenthesized subgroup: Bold Stuff
```

It may work for some simple cases. However, in more complex cases it might be tricky to deal with tag overlapping, for example see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags):

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by
> regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML...

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
title = soup.find('b').text
```