# Find everything between two tags html in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to get a text that will be in the first list `<ul>` after a title in  `<b>` that will contain a Keyword, like the following:

```
<b> anything </b>
<p> KEYWORD </p> 
<b> anything </b>
<b> anything KEYWORD anything </b> #this is the title that I want
<some tag> anything <some tag>
<ul> 
# this is the TEXT what I want 
</ul>
```

What I want is that the RE consider only the text that is in the third `<b>`, but the RE that I wrote get the first `<b>`, the keyword of the `<p>` and the second `</b>`.

Thats my RE:
`re.search(r'<b>.*?(' + keyword + ').*?</b>.*?<ul>(.*?)</ul>')`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Wouldn't an HTML parser solve this problem more effectively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Regex - find string between html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120584/python-regex-find-string-between-html-tags)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Im using HTML parser too, but in this part I have to use regex. And about the duplicate, thats not exactly my question, in the other solution they are not considering multiples equal tags, which is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this were just text, focus on the inner `<b>..</b>` like this

`(?is)<b>(?:(?!</?b>).)*?(keyword)(?:(?!</?b>).)*?</b>.*?<ul>\s*(.*?)\s*</ul>`

https://regex101.com/r/3WwDXM/1

Expanded

```
 (?is)

 <b>
 (?: (?! </?b> ) .)*?
 ( keyword )                   # (1)
 (?: (?! </?b> ) .)*?
 </b> 

 .*? 

 <ul> \s* 
 ( .*? )                       # (2)
 \s* </ul>
```

Comment: Hi, i try your solution but its still getting the wrong tag

Comment: in my case, the keyword its a group of OR, that is: keyword = keyword1|keyword2|keyword3. Do you think this may be why it's going wrong?

Comment: `'(?is)<b>(?:(?!</?b>).)*?(' + keywords+ ')(?:(?!</?b>).)*?</b>.*?<ul>\s*(.*?)\s*</ul>' `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this would do what you'd like to extract:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<b> anything </b>
<p> KEYWORD </p>
<b> anything </b>
<b> anything KEYWORD anything </b> #this is the title that I want
<some tag> anything <some tag>
<ul>
# this is the TEXT what I want
</ul>

<ul>
# this is not the TEXT what I want
</ul>

'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


b_tags = soup.findAll('b')
ul_tag = soup.find('ul')

desired_keyword = 'KEYWORD'

for b in b_tags:
    if desired_keyword in b.text:
        print(ul_tag.text.strip())
```

#### Output

```
# this is the TEXT what I want
```

Comment: hi, emma! thats not exactly what I need. The set of texts that I have to extract from these lists does not have just one list. Thats why I have to find the title first and second get the list

Comment: Thank you, emma! Thats not exactly what I was thinking, but your code can help me solve it differently <3